# Write a program that displays a grid of numbers and the totals of each row in a screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

> Write a program that displays a grid of numbers and the totals of each row in a screen
>
> The following program displays a grid of numbers and the totals of
>   each row. Fill in the missing function definitions for this program.
>   That is, write the functions `sumRow():` and `display():`
>
> ```
> wn = Screen()           #The graphics window
> nums = [[4,3,2,1],      #The numbers to be displayed to the screen
>         [8,7,6,5],
>         [12,11,10,9],
>         [16,15,14,13],
>         [20,19,18,17]]
> n = len(nums)           #The number of rows
> m = len(nums[0])        #The number of columns (assumes all same length)
> wn.setworldcoordinates(-0.5,n-0.5,m+2,-1.0)
>
> for row in range(n):
>     rowTotal = sumRow(nums[row])   #Returns the sum of inputted list
>     for col in range(m):
>         display(nums[row][col], col, row) #Displays entry at (col,row)
>     display("=", col+1, row)              #Displays "=" at (col+1,row)
>     display(rowTotal, col+2, row)         #Displays row total at (col+2,row)
>
> wn.exitonclick()  #Closes the graphics window when mouse is clicked
> ```

So I added this function in to the above program. I am still confused. Please help!

```
from turtle import*
def sumRow(nums):
  row = sum(nums[0])+ sum(num[1]) + sum(num[2]) + sum(num[3]) + sum(num[4])
  return row

def display(num, col, row)
  pen = Turtle()
  pen.up()
  pen.goto(col,row)
  pen.down()
  pen.write(nums[row][co1])
```

Comment: Help with what exactly? What problems are you having, where are you stuck? Are you getting exceptions, unexpected output? What output where you expecting instead? Please include such information *in your question*.

Comment: I am not sure whether the function `sumRow(nums)` making sense.

Comment: Do *you* think it makes sense? If not, why not? Does anything happen when you call that function with a list of numbers? You could just put that function into the interactive Python interpreter and call it with a row. What happens when you call `sumRow([4, 3, 2, 1])` with it?

Comment: Please don't alter your question to incorporate answers. That would invalidate my answer, even if you have *other* problems. Questions shoud be useful to future visitors as well, so that they can judge if their problem is similar enough that answers could help them too.

Answer (score 2):

`sum()` takes a *sequence* of values to sum. You are giving it individual values instead, which will produce an exception:

```
>>> sum(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

That's because individual integers cannot be iterated over; iteration is *looping*, taking each value in turn.

Just pass in the whole row to `sum()`, and return the result of the function:

```
def sumRow(nums):
    total = sum(nums)
    return total
```

You can simplify that down to:

```
def sumRow(nums):
    return sum(nums)
```

or even just do:

```
sumRow = sum
```

and it'll all do the exact same thing, produce the sum total of all values in the list `nums` passed to the function.

Your display function is passed the actual value to write as `num`, you don't have to use indexing on `nums` to access that number anymore:

```
def display(num, col, row):
    pen = Turtle()
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(col,row)
    pen.down()
    pen.write(num)
```

This way the function also works to write the `=` character and the total for the row!